# Lateral defender does not help my wing

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2011

Premise: I really don't know the soccer technical terms in English so I hope you'll understand me.

I'm playing a classical 4-4-2. When one of my wings has the ball I can't get my lateral defenders to help them. They remain behind the centerfield line instead of going forward to get the ball and cross.

The UI is a "little bit" ugly, I can't find any option to give the instruction to my player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Team Style` in the tactics screen, `Player Support` and `Attacking Style` are the key settings.

A higher `Player Support` value will make players more likely to make forward runs ahead of the man in possession.

A higher `Attacking Style` value will make players more likely to make runs wide, rather than through the middle.

Perhaps look at Barcelona's tactics, as they tend to have very aggressive full-backs.

Comment: Ok so that does not depend on specific instructions to a player, right? I mean basically I want asymmetrical full-backs (tnx for the term). Only the left one has to sustain the wing, on the right I have krasic as wing and he can handle it.

Comment: @dierre I don't think the tactics system is in-depth enough to do individual instructions, but, just moving the player further back might help. Maybe try using less aggressive team instructions and changing the more attacking full-back's role to `WB`. An ugly solution would be to try giving the defensive full-back a `CB` role.

Answer (score 2):

Besides setting the team style, you can also use 1-2 pass more often to make your sidebacks more aggressive in attacking.

Also, if you are confident enough by your domination in opposite half, set both your sidebacks to wing backs.